# Proper root path for asp.net application (in dev and on the server)

Tags: asp.net, path, root

In my personal dev environment, I have an asp.net application on it's own ip (127.0.0.2), thus root is always "/"

On the server, it's in an app, which comes across as "servername.com/appname/"

I'm building up hyperlinks to files in strings and can't seem to parse out the filenames properly on the server. They come out with the "servername.com" but not the appname part.

What am I missing?

I call a web helper class (shown below) to get the paths for a menu:

```
public static string getOnsiteAdministratorMenu()
        {
            string syllabusSearchURL = "/admin/syllabus_Search.aspx";

            return "<ul id=\"nav\"><li><a href=\"EnrollmentLookup.aspx\">Enrollment Search</a></li>" +
            "<li><a href=\"OnsiteEnrollment_AddNew.aspx\">Enrollment Add</a></li>" +
            "<li><a href=\"ViewSingleDocument.aspx\">Document Search</a></li>" +
            "<li><a href=\"/Admin/SyllabusAdd.aspx\">Add Syllabus</a></li>" +
            "<li><a href=\"" + syllabusSearchURL + "\">Edit Syllabus</a></li>" +
            "<li><a href=\"Course_add.aspx\">Add Course</a></li>" +
            "<li><a href=\"Group_add.aspx\">Add Group</a></li>" +
            "<li><a href=\"GroupSearch.aspx\">Groups</a></li>" +
            "<li><a href=\"Admin/Admin_GradeChanges.aspx\">Audit Grade Changes</a></li></ul>";
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the other answers here are correct, but I just wanted to add something.  To do what they suggest and dynamically return HTML content you can use the HtmlGenericContro class  Then you would add the nested controls inside.

```
    HtmlGenericControl adminMenu = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
    HtmlGenericControl liItem  = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
    HyperLink link = new HyperLink();

    link.NavigateUrl = "~EnrollmentLookup.aspx";
    liItem.Controls.Add(link);
    adminMenu.Controls.Add(liItem);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

    adminMenu.RenderControl(hw);
    return sb.ToString();
```

Although you may be even better off yet using a User Control to define your AdminMenu

Answer (score 0):

when you use server controls, you can use the ~ to create a relative path which is always correct (localhost and on server):

```
<asp:HyperLink id="hyperlink1" NavigateUrl="~/EnrollmentLookup.aspx"
              Text="Enrollment Search" runat="server"/>
```

In case you want to access physical devices using System.IO, you can call Server.MapPath

```
Server.MapPath("~/log/data.txt");
```

If you need an absolute path you can use

```
VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/EnrollmentLookup.aspx");
```

But I would suggest, that you use a UserControl or a asp:Repeater to generate the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

add this before URL `ResolveUrl("~");`